# How to call the value when ng-model with ng-repeat is used? Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem of ng-model not geting called in controller if I use ng-repeat. As you can see below, in sports section, I get the sports value undefined when the form is submitted in controller however for demands, I get whatever I input into the field meaning it gets the value. 
I tried to identify by id however it does not work as well.

```
<form ng-submit="sendDetails(sports, demands)" ng-class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Sports:</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="sports" ng-repeat="sports in selectedSports" type="text" disabled/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="demands" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
angular.factory('sportsFactory', function($http) {
return {
    postAdministrationEntries: function ($sports, $demands){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('sports', $sports);
        fd.append('demands', $demands);
        return $http.post('/sendDetails', fd,{
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$scope.sportsValues =[];
$scope.sendDetails = function($sports, $demands){
    if($demands.length > 0 ){
        var sendDetailsPromise = sportsFactory.sendDetails($sports, $demands);
        sendDetailsPromise.success(function (data){
            $sportsValues = data;
};
```

Comment: The code has problems because the `ng-repeat` creates child scopes and is putting the `ng-model` on those child scope. Remember the best practice: **Always put a dot `.` in your ng-models**. Read [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Comment: Is there some reason that the server needs to post using `multipart/form-data`? It is more efficient to POST with the AngularJS default of `application/json`.

Comment: Is the `selectedSports` array an array of objects or an array of primitives?

Comment: @georgeawg Hi, I am using a form to post taking these values there I declared multipart/form-data. Is there any alternatives (I will look on application/json)?  selectedSports is array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because each loop through you are assigning the same model each time. You need to use the $index of the loop in combination with the model:

```
<input class="form-control"
  ng-model="sports[$index]"
  ng-repeat="sports in selectedAttributes track by $index"
  type="text" disabled />
```

Although I'm sure you realise that by being disabled, the input is never going to actually be changed from the model you give it (assuming it's not empty).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply however it still giving me undefined value or any empty value.

Comment: Where is your controller code? You show the factory, but I don't see a controller.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't give value in initial factory stage however I have edited the code with the controller now. Feel free to look at the controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to work with an array of objects, is to have the `ng-model` use a property of each object:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.itemList = [
    {name: 'apple', value: 11},
    {name: 'orange', value: 22},
    {name: 'peach', value: 33},
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h3>ng-repeat DEMO</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
       {{item.name}} <input ng-model="item.value" />
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{itemList | json}}
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go.